# rewrite urls with GET reqs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how do I configure my .htaccess rewrite rules to accomodate GET requests?

Currently, `/manager/page` goes to: `?dept=manager&n=page` however, some pages have additional GET reqs, and so this rule doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?dept=$1&n=$2 [QSA]
```

I would need: `?dept=manager&n=page&id&etc=etc` to go to: `/manager/page/id/5/etc/6` however, not all pages present the same method of id input, IE. some pages used id, others catid, and others, bugid, so it's a bit difficult.

Thanks :)

UPDATED: END URL - `id/5/etc/6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sepcify a different rule.

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_METHOD}  "GET"
RewriteRule --your rule--
```

Comment: How would I write the rule though?

Answer (score 0):

If your input methods are really that varied, you should use multiple RewriteRules for each different format.

Comment: Well, most of them are id however the forum is stuck with catid and threadid

Comment: @ct2k7 Well, add rewrite rules for catid and threadid, then use the default rule for id.

Comment: what would they be? Spent an hour trying to figure it out :/ I'm getting useless nowadays :/